# Why label tapgesture not working in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, label, uitapgesturerecognizer

code: with this code `edit profile` showing in blue colour but tap gesture not working.. if i click on "edit profile" then the its always goes to `tapLabel` method's else part

always prints `print("Tapped none")`... where am i wrong. please guide

```
 fileprivate let text = "You have not completed your profile. Kindly go to edit profile and complete your profile."

class DashboardVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.yellowLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    underlinetermsAndPolicy()
}
    
let termsRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "edit profile")

@objc func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    
    if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: yellowLabel, inRange: termsRange) {
        print("Tapped profile")
    }
    else {
        print("Tapped none")
    }
}

func underlinetermsAndPolicy(){
    
    yellowLabel.text = text
    let clickableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: yellowLabel.text!)
    
    clickableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: termsRange)
    
    yellowLabel.attributedText = clickableString
    yellowLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(tapLabel(gesture:))))
}
}
```

extension code:

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
    
    // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    
    // Configure textContainer
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
    let labelSize = label.bounds.size
    textContainer.size = labelSize
    
    // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
    let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
    let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
    
    let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
    
    let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
    
    let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
    
    return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
}
}
```

in console always prints this:

> Tapped none

Comment: What is `didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label:inRange:)`?

Comment: @Larme, updated the code with extension

Comment: And if you check the value inside that method, does it seems correct? What about the debugging part of that method? Also, any reason why you don't want to use a `UITextView` instead, which is made for these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line in the UITapGestureRecognizer  extension

```
let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
```

with following one

```
let textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: label.text ?? "")
```

Comment: This will only work if the text is plain text only. If the attributedText is combined of lots of different fonts include font size, ... then it will cause wrong.

Comment: I guess the tap action is calculated depending on text location and length then why would font, color, and the number of attributes affect it? Is there any reference or article so that I can improve my knowledge

Comment: The current code is recreating a text layout to find where the user has tapped. If you use a font which is 50 times bigger, then the position would be wrong. The colors won't matter, but font will definitely matter... as paragraph (like centered text, etc), kernel, etc.

Comment: @Larme I understood the flaw that you indicated thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think the `locationOfTouchInTextContainer` you have calculate wrong.

Try this instead

```
let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
var textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
textBoundingBox.origin = CGPoint(x: label.bounds.midX - textBoundingBox.size.width / 2, y: label.bounds.midY - textBoundingBox.size.height / 2)

let touchPoint = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
let index = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: touchPoint, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
```

Comment: leave my code(i have given this calculation for terms and conditions), can you give total code for my above line... `"You have not completed your profile. Kindly go to edit profile and complete your profile."
`

Comment: here `edit profile` in blue colour and touchable

Comment: Dear @swiftDev, you have the ``index`` which is the character index from your string. Just do simple code to check if that index is in your ``edit profile`` is not.

Comment: here `termsRange = 50, 12` showing corrct but it always goes to else part... with your answer code also

Comment: Dear @swiftDev, have you try ``return targetRange.contains(index)``?